# How to cancel the alarm manager daily notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

In my app I use alarm manager to daily show notifications, but I want to create an option for users to cancel the daily notifications.On user click the working alarm manager has to permanently stop.

How to achieve this?

This is the method that is being called on app installation and then notification starts appearing daily, how to cancel it permanently?

```
 public  void AlaramNotification() {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(StartActivity.this,
                0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

            if (now.after(cal)) {
                Log.d("Hey","Added a day");
               cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, broadcast);


        }
        else {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = 
(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getActivity(StartActivity.this, 0, 
intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.cancel(broadcast);
```

Answer (score 0):

When user cancels daily notification use **cancel()** on **alarmManager** with pendingintent as shown below to stop alarmManager.

```
alarmManager.cancel(broadcast);
```

You may need to make **broadcast** a global variable.